# Improving Emacs package descriptions on melpa, elpa, and marmalade repositories

Tags: emacs, repository, emacs24, elpa

The Emacs package descriptions are sometimes not very descriptive or have typos. How can users improve this?

Is there a bugtracker, or an public repository like GitHub for contributions?

You should **not** use `M-x report-emacs-bug`, because the repositories are not part of the Emacs code itself.

Comment: For GNU ELPA packages, use `report-emacs-bug`. For third-party package archives, either email the package author, or else look for an appropriate bug tracker (e.g. anything with a repository on github or similar will have its own bug tracker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The development of marmalade takes place on GitHub. All bugs and requests concerning marmalade should be sent as issue to the [marmalade repository](https://github.com/nicferrier/marmalade)

I have found a contact for `elpa` here:
http://tromey.com/elpa/upload.html

I found no bug tracker the other repositories yet.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x report-emacs-bug` is the official way.  This submits a bug to the `debbugs.gnu.org` bug tracker.

Comment: I thought the bugtracker would be rather for the emacs program and not for the elpa, melpa, marlmelade repositories. Are you shure?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize "Emacs package" was meant as for the non-bundled ones (IOW I didn't read the title, only the question).  `M-x report-emacs-bug` is only for Emacs's bundled packages, indeed, although it can also be used for GNU ELPA packages.  For melpa, marmalade, etc... I'd recommend you `M-x find-library RET <thepackage> RET` and read the beginning of the file where you'll hopefully find some contact information.

Comment: I do not think that the maintainer always uploads his packages and maintains the description. I rather assume this is done by volunteers and by the repository maintainer himself.